# SET /a var1 = var1 + 1 /a not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file, variables, logic, artificial-intelligence

So here is my code

```
IF %FIT% leq %FITLAST% set /a "MUTA=MUTA-1" ELSE set /A "MUTA=MUTA+1"
```

This is for AI, it sees if this generation is fitter than the last one or not and adjusts the likelyhood of repeating the same characteristics or magnifying them. Don't worry about the AI side that is sound I have made this in java I am just moving it over to batch for a challenge and am having all sorts of syntax errors xD

Essentially if this generation is less fit or equally fit to the last, then decrease MUTA by 1 (reducing the likely hood of repeating the same action. If this generation is more fit than the last then increase MUTA by 1 which will increase the likely hood of repeating the same action.

The issue is where it sees /a as a command on its own and obviously can't recognise it as it is just part of SETs syntax.

EDIT: THIS WAS ANSWERED ^^^^

Okay I hope you can help me with the problems caused in the extended code as well:

```
IF "%FIT%" leq "%FITLAST%" (
set /a "MUTA=MUTA-1"
) ELSE (
set /A "MUTA=MUTA+1"
)

if %num%>50(
    SET DIR=DOWN
    if %num%>(50+%MUTA%) SET DIR=UP
)
pause
if %num%<50(
    SET DIR=RIGHT
    if %num%<(%MUTA%) SET DIR=LEFT
)
```

This doesn't return anything it just closes the console even with the pause command in there. I am looking here for an answer that corrects my inevitably wrong syntax on something that I have missed out instead of reorganising it to solve a problem as this is definitely just my syntax being wrong.

Comment: You should isolate your `If` command from your `Else` command using parentheses: `If %FIT% LEq %FITLAST% (Set /A MUTA -=1) Else Set /A MUTA +=1`

Comment: If you know that your variables are numeric, do not enclose them with doublequotes, as this makes string comparisons. Try this at the command prompt to see: `If 102 GTR 29 (@Echo greater) Else @Echo less` now use the doublequotes: `If "102" GTR "29" (Echo greater) Else Echo less`.

Comment: It is all working now apart from the code within the REM ------- above, there is a syntax error which I am overlooking but it causes it to cut off and not get to the pause command.

Comment: Did you read and try my previous comment(s)? Also you should be using, `50 (`, not `50(`. In order to get proper help with your script, you should edit it again to ensure that all values and their types are known to us, the readers. Currently, for example, we have no idea of what `:L` contains or what the values of `x` and `y` are! When you use `Set`, as opposed to `Set /A` the syntax should be `Set "variable=value"`, when comparing string variables you should be using this syntax, `If "%variable1%"=="%variable2%"` or `If "%variable1%" Equ "%variable2%"`, _(optionally with the `/I` switch)_.

Comment: You need a space between the value you are comparing and the parentheses.  Also, your last 4 `IF` commands have syntax problems.  I highly suggest you read the help file for the `IF` and `SET` commands.

Comment: @SamuelPollard, you need to revisit this question and make a decision; either `rollback` your question to `revision 2` or edit it to include fully explained and reproducible code which responders can help you with. As it stands, the question has an accepted answer which does not match the question. Those interested in helping with the most recent edit will be less willing to do so because of that accepted answer, but future readers will be unable to understand how one correlates with the other.

Comment: `if DIR=`: the `=` is not a valid comparison operator, use `==` instead; and you need to read the variable like `%DIR%`...

Comment: Due to the elapsed time, I have rolled back your edit so that the accepted answer is relevant. I would advise that you create a new question, should you wish to receive further help with your script.

Comment: Thank you and it is all resolved now and the program is completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using it wrong. You should use parenthesis:

```
IF %FIT% leq %FITLAST% (
set /a "MUTA=MUTA-1"
) ELSE (
set /A "MUTA=MUTA+1"
)
```

To understand the `if` statement better, run from cmdline `if /?`

On the edit. You cannot use `>` or `<` for bigger/smaller as you need to use `gtr`, `lss`, `equ` etc and have whitespace between your number and the parenthesis.

```
if %num% lss 50 (
```

or

```
if %num% gtr 50 (
```

Please read the `if /?` help, it shows:

where compare-op may be one of:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

Comment: I have amended my question to include a problem caused literally in the next few lines can you take a look again please I think it is going to be a syntax error.

Comment: again, why are you changing methods?? You cannot use > and <. will update my answer.

Comment: okay I have amended the code with the lss gtr etc, I have edited my post above with the updated code, there is a syntax error between the lines I have highlighted in it. Please have a look.

Comment: This question was already answered, you cannot change the content each time as your question will be closed. Please create a new question.

Comment: Gerhard, the answer was actually incorrect though, please see my second comment under the question to see why. _(there's nothing stopping @SamuelPollard from unmarking an accepted answer, if they are not satisfied that their problem has been solved)_. It's a little unfair to tell them that they cannot change their question when you've already provided a changed answer to a subsequent initial question change.

Comment: @Compo please see first version of question by OP, where my answer solved the question, then he had a second edit and again my edit solved the problem, then he completely changed the question to what it is now. He is welcome to unmark my answer as correct, if he feels that I did not solve his __original__ question.

Comment: @Compo oh, you mean the quoble quoting.. fixed that now. Thanks, but the question changed quite dramatically since posted. Also, after I gave the `if /?` help option as well. Keep in mind, if you write a script for a user, you spend time to help, they can then change the question completely and you have to rewrite it again to accommodate.. This is a similar case, the question was about and `else` statement, then a unrelated comparison issue and then a syntax error... :)

Comment: @Gerhard, I'm satisfied that your answer now caters for the initial question change, and can agree that they shouldn't change it again. My suggestion is that you include a note that your answer assumes that `%FIT%`, `%FITLAST%`, `%MUTA%` and `%num%` are always integers, and rollback their question edit up to the point your answer covered the question. _Oh and clean up any unnecessary comments above, I'll do the same_.